What will a cleanly interrupted restore with Déjà Dup have done?
The question title is vague partly because the documentation / help and UI are, but below I say what I need to know.
Three days ago (2024-05-13, Mon) I started using Déjà Dup, got it to make a full backup of my home directory tree on a USB stick and told it to make weekly backups. Today (2024-05-16, Thu) I thought I had probably accidentally permanently deleted a file or even directory (Shift-Delete on the wrong side of a split screen in Dolphin!), and that this was a good chance to try out the restore function. I inserted the stick and started Déjà Dup from the (OpenSuse Leap) start menu, I do not know which I did first) and was surprised to see it said it was backing up, though I do not recall having said it should back up on Thursdays. I presumed it would be an incremental backup, and it did indeed take nothing like as long as the original backup.
Once it was finished it exited, so I started it again and asked it to restore one directory sub-tree, worth about 28 out of 400 Gb, by selecting it in the appropriate dialogue. It stomped around silently for quite a while, asked for a password, stomped around a little more, then started saying it was restoring ... more or less everything, it seemed! Since I had just spent quite a long time tidying up, reorganising and freeing up space, I was alarmed, and eventually sent it a TERM signal, as I could find no way to stop it in its UI. Of course I specified to restore from the full backup, as I had already (probably) deleted before the incremental backup.
This leaves me with a few relatively urgent questions:

Is there a chance that it has left something corrupt in the tree it was working on?

I.e. does it handle TERM cleanly?


Is there a log somewhere of what it actually did?
Was it really restoring all the files it said it was?
Was it going to revert some or all of my system to the state at the time of the full backup, losing recent changes?

and a few more fundamental ones:

Is it possible to specify several files / directories to be restored, or select on other criteria such as time? — I saw no such options.
Is it possible to specify a policy when a file to be restored would overwrite a later change?

If not, how can one restore files to a directory on which one has worked?


What is its policy when a file to be backed up is in use?
Is there a good way of getting more insight into what it does, apart from reading the code?
Is there a good way or getting more control over the process?

Is there perhaps a different GUI tool offering me full control of the underlying functionality? (I am prepared but reluctant to learn rsync and/or duplicity and roll my own.)



At first I quite liked the minimal nature of the UI, but now it seems to me to lack many essential options. I know one should RTFM, but this FM was F vague on many points. I have now turned off automatic backup, and may even deinstall this tool.

You have a whole lot of questions there. I will address one of them:

Is it possible to specify several files / directories to be restored, or select on other criteria such as time?

This is written using Deja-Dup v.44 on Debian 12.5
When one selects "restore" in the GUI, DD shows a "scanning backup files" icon and runs for a while, proportional to how big your backup is, it seems.
The user is then presented with a file-manager type interface showing the files and folders backed up. To "specify several files / directories to be restored" you browse to them and select them.
The date of the backup is at the lower right of the screen. To "select on other criteria such as time" you can choose which backup you want to restore from.
Then you click the Restore button at the bottom. It will ask you where to put the restored files, original location or a location you specify.
Upon clicking Restore again, it will do its magic.

Thanks. I must check my version, because my impression of the UI was that could only select one item to restore. By “select on time” I meant a finer selection by file dates, not just backup date.

I was using version 40.6 on Open Suse Leap 15.3.
